# how to configure a datasource with embedded tomcat in heroku

Tags: jdbc, heroku, datasource, jndi

Please know that I cannot use spring. I need a datasource with a JNDI lookup for use in persistence.xml. Is it possible? If spring is the only way to do this, then that is a disappointment.

Answer (score 3):

Check out: https://github.com/jesperfj/webapp-with-jndi

Provides an example app that does exactly that.